# Black Screen On Boot When Selecting Nvidia Driver

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

Thank you so much for reading this!

I recently installed Xubuntu and when I select the nvidia driver 390 when I restart I get a black screen.  I have a nvidia quadro 2000 and that is my only recommended driver.  The X.Org one is the other option and it thankfully does work.

I have not figured out how to restart the computer from the blackscreen besides just pulling the plug which I hate to do.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> does nothing nor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> or the like.

After reading a ton of posts on similar issues I did find that I could load grub into the command menu and I followed some steps to restore the X.org X server -- nouveau display.

Is there any way I can use the driver without getting a black screen?  And if I do get a black screen is there any way I can at least restart it without pulling the plug?

Thank you so much for your time!!!!

Comment: Sounds like the driver is not working with your card. Is it possible you are using a different video card? Maybe a built in instead the add-on?